# How to insert and retrieve data display button using sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I cant't get all data to display in `button` when click on button get. please help me.

```
 public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE = "Test";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "savedata";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_SEX = "sex";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE, null,VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_SEX + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    public void Insertdata(Data data){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, data.getName());
        values.put(KEY_SEX, data.getSex());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    }
    public List<Data> getAllData(){
        List<Data> listData = new ArrayList<Data>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Data data = new Data();
                data.setId(c.getInt(0));
                data.setName(c.getString(1));
                data.setSex(c.getString(2));
                listData.add(data);

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return listData;
    }
}

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        sex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_sex);
        btn_get = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get);
        btn_name = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_name);
        btn_sex = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sex);
        btn_id = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        _name = name.getText().toString();
        _sex = sex.getText().toString();
        data = new Data(_name,_sex);
        btn_save =( Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

        SaveData();
        getData();

    }
    public void SaveData(){
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    db.Insertdata(data);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SuccessFull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    public void getData(){
        btn_get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                  if (currentData == null){
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }else {
                       currentData = db.getAllData();
                       btn_id.setText(String.valueOf(data.getId()));
                       btn_name.setText(data.getName());
                       btn_sex.setText(data.getSex());
                 }

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you be a little bit more specific about the expected and the actual behavior? Also you should consider including only the relevant parts of your code instead of uploading your entire class. Makes it easier to follow your thoughts and find a answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up badly. That's all I can suggest-
   1. Create a class (for example "MyClass") that will extend AppCompatActivity and contains the view.
   2. You've already created a class named DBHelper for your Database       manipulation. It extends SQLiteOpenHelper.
   3. Create object of DBHelper class inside the onCreate method of MyClass and access your database. onCreate method in MyClass will be looking similar to this-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    sex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_sex);
    btn_get = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get);
    btn_name = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_name);
    btn_sex = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sex);
    btn_id = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    _name = name.getText().toString();
    _sex = sex.getText().toString();
    data = new Data(_name,_sex);
    btn_save =( Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                db.Insertdata(data);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),      "SuccessFull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    btn_get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (currentData == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    currentData = db.getAllData();
                    btn_id.setText(String.valueOf(data.getId()));
                    btn_name.setText(data.getName());
                    btn_sex.setText(data.getSex());
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that, this might help.

Comment: Thank a lot! 
I create 3 same class
but when I post my code then collected as a class :D